# Short story collection involving a beast with impenetrable armor eating an old man and getting indigestion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Here's what I can remember:

In one short story, a beast with impenetrable armor eats an old man and gets indigestion.

In another, an adventurer kills that same beast, hacks off its armor plating, and makes a fortune on it.

In another, a young girl emerges from poverty by working as a cook for an innkeeper named Barrelgut.

And in the last one that I can remember, two wizards battle, and one is struck in his invisible hand by a snake that the other one conjured.

All stories are women together in this book, and I thought the book referenced a land of Elsewhen or something? Does this ring a bell for anyone?

Answer (score 8):

You're looking for *[Barrow](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1299907.Barrow)* by John Deakins. There is the purple beast, from another plane of reality, with impenetrable armour, who eats the old man and gets indigestion. The would-be hero, that accidentally kills the beast and makes a fortune selling it's armor plating. The young girl from the swamp lands/slum who gets a job cooking for the inn keeper - Barrelgut. And regarding the two wizards, one is supposedly missing a hand, but it's invisible, and gets poisoned from a conjured snake.

[image]